# how can I call fragment from activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

how to call Fragment from Activity. I am using below code.here MainFragment extends Fragment only.

```
  MainFragment  mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
```

but  "getSupportFragmentManager()" in my Activity class is not supported.

Comment: Using Fragment from support library?

Comment: when i used support library for FragmentActivity then my buttons are not clickable.

Comment: Do you want support fragments below api level 11 or not

Comment: yes i want support lib below api level 11.

Comment: Then you need to Extend `FragmentActivity` Your import of fragment should be from support library. Button click has nothing to with all these

Comment: ok thanks @Raghunandan I think I got it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48590/discussion-between-amar-raj-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 3):

You need extend your activity from `FragmentActivity`

Comment: I made my Activity to FragmentActivity its woking fine but now my buttons are not clickable.

Comment: As they said in comments, buttons have nothing to do with this, probably you are missing listeners or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentBId);
mainFragment.performSomeTask();
```