# How to call fragment from a java class in android?

Tags: android

I am calling a one fragment from a java class, on click of one textview I am calling one fragment this is my code of onclick.

```
returnTheProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getFragmentManager();
              FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
              ProductReturnFragment productReturnFragment = new ProductReturnFragment();
              fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_marketplace_forms, new MarketPlaceFormsActivity());
              fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
              fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
          });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I call fragment from activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069865/how-can-i-call-fragment-from-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
From class call Activity on which you are calling fragments like below code.

Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallingActivity.class);

         intent.putExtra("key", "value");
          context.startActivity(returnFormIntent);

In your CallingActivity define below code.
private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
private YourFragment yourFragment;

if (getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      yourFragment = new YourFragment();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_your_fragment, yourFragment);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

like above we can call fragments from other nonActivity classes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import the following two statements:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And,

```
private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
.....
```

Then on your click listener you can write below code :

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_marketplace_forms, new ProductReturnFragment());
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Hope you get your answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Add like :

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (isBackPressed)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout,attachedfragmentHere);
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```